# S3 object as gensim LineSentence

Tags: python, amazon-s3, nlp, gensim, doc2vec

Is it possible to use a txt or jsonl file in an s3 bucket as the `corpus_file` input for a gensim Doc2Vec model? I am looking for something of the form:

```
Doc2Vec(corpus_file="s3://bucket_name/subdir/sample.jsonl")
```

When I run the above line, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Parameter corpus_file must be a valid path to a file, got 's3://bucket_name/subdir/sample.jsonl' instead.
```

I have also tried creating an iterator object that iterates through the file and yields its lines, and passing it as the `corpus_file` argument. But I get the same TypeError.

Please note that I am specifically looking to use the `corpus_file` argument instead of the `documents.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `corpus_file` mode requires random-seek access to the file for its technique, which involves every worker thread opening its own unique file view on distinct ranges of the file. Such access is not well-supported for S3 (HTTP GET) access.

To use `corpus_file` mode, download the file to a local volume whose filesystem offers efficient seek access.

Or, supply things as a corpus iterable - which can re-iterate over a remote streamed file multiple times, but won't achieve the same high thread utilization. (From an iteratable, even if you have 16+ cores, you'll usually get optimal throughput with no more than 6-12 worker threads – even *if* you've eliminated IO & expensive in-iterable preprocesing from the setup. The exact optimal number of workers depends on other model parameters – it's especially sensitive to `vector_size`, `negative`, & `window`.)